# transform3d not changing after alteration

Tags: html, css, transform

This is the default code:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); width: 337px; height:480px; opacity: 1;" class="events-item one-four onsite technical isotope-item">
    <div class="events-image"> <img src="img/01_th.jpg"  alt="events 1"> </div>
    <a href="" title="MYB V3.0" class="open-project">
    <div class="project-overlay">
      <div class="project-info">
        <div class="zoom-icon"></div>
        <h4 class="project-name">MYB V3.0</h4>
        <p class="project-categories">Onsite</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </a> 
</div>
```

When i altered it as:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 337px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); width: 337px; height:480px; opacity: 1;" class="events-item one-four onsite technical isotope-item">
  <div class="events-image"> <img src="img/01_th.jpg"  alt="events 1"> </div>
  <a href="" title="MYB V3.0" class="open-project">
    <div class="project-overlay">
      <div class="project-info">
        <div class="zoom-icon"></div>
        <h4 class="project-name">MYB V3.0</h4>
        <p class="project-categories">Onsite</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a> 
</div>
```

Nothing changes

When I inspect the element in the browser it shows the default code
like this:
[image]
Anyone Please help

Comment: Awesome, the added code helps see the context of what you are doing, but it would still be helpful to know what all these css classes are doing. ie: open-project, project-overlay, project-info, ect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just made a mockup with the code you have and its difficult to tell what your problem is exactly with such a small sample, The elements surrounding this code, and the css classes you did not provide for us to see could very well be making a difference that I'm not seeing however this is what I discovered.

You have assigned a `width: 337px`but there is no `height` on the element, therefore it does not show up at all. When I gave a `height: 200px` to the element, and changed the x Position in the `translate3d` to `337px. The object did shift right`337px`.

Once again, given the small code sample you provided, for all I know you already assign a height in one of the many classes that is at the end of your tag, for more detailed help please provide more info for me and I can take a deeper look.

Good luck!

**Side Note:**

Good CSS practice is to avoid using the style attribute for anything other than prototyping, creating a CSS class is more modular and allows for better code-reuse.

**UPDATE**

I ran the new code you posted in a google chrome browser. The `transform3d` is acting as expected, and moving the xPos of the div by 337px.

Here are some screenshots:

**Result without the 337px offset**
[image: Result with 337px offset]

**Result with the 337px offset**
[image: Result without the 337px offset]

As you can see the offset that you are adding is happening, but it seems that transform3d is not a universally supported tag yet, if an offset affect is what you want to achieve there are many more traditional ways to achieve this such as `left: 337px`

Comment: <div style="position: absolute; left: 337px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); width: 337px; height:480px; opacity: 1;" class="events-item one-four onsite technical isotope-item">
   <div class="events-image"> <img src="img/01_th.jpg"  alt="events 1"> </div>
    <a href="" title="MYB V3.0" class="open-project">
       <div class="project-overlay">
         <div class="project-info">
           <div class="zoom-icon"></div>
            <h4 class="project-name">MYB V3.0</h4>
            <p class="project-categories">Onsite</p>
          </div>
</div></a> </div>

Comment: is this enough!! @unome

Comment: please format this and addition it to your original post, but yes that helps.

Comment: @IllllIllSanthoshKumarIllllI  I just copy and pasted the new code you placed, and it seems to work as expected. Is it working for you now? Also, if my answer helped, please upvote/accept.

Comment: but when i checked "inspect element" the code shows the default one in all browsers :(

Comment: In your final sentence, I think you mean "style attribute", not "style tag"; what you're saying makes no sense otherwise.

Comment: @IllllIllSanthoshKumarIllllI did my modified post help solve the problem?

Comment: I didn't modify your code, the screenshots are from what you gave me running in google chrome.

Comment: `<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(337px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); width: 337px; height:480px; opacity: 1;" class="events-item one-four onsite technical isotope-item">
  <div class="events-image"> <img src="img/01_th.jpg"  alt="events 1"> </div>
  <a href="" title="MYB V3.0" class="open-project">
    <div class="project-overlay">
      <div class="project-info">
        <div class="zoom-icon"></div>
        <h4 class="project-name">MYB V3.0</h4>
        <p class="project-categories">Onsite</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
`

Comment: The above is what is running in the second screenshot.

Comment: But chk my screenshot in updated question it still shows that :(

Comment: If the code that you have pasted is not displaying how it does on my screenshot, it must be because you have a conflicting css class defined that is overriding what the one you posted would normally do. I would right click and inspect element to see what is actually happening and why.